# Android /sdcard in ES File Explorer and other file browsers show a black screen for long time (10+ minutes)

Tags: screen

I'm using Android ICS 4.0.4

I'm getting ES File Explorer, Solid Explorer, File Manager and other file browsers with a black screen for almost 10 minutes or sometimes more.

I found these lines in logcat for ES File Explorer:

```
W/ActivityManager(  388): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
W/ActivityManager(  388): Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{4159fd50 com.estrongs.android.pop/.view.FileExplorerActivity} D/StateMachine(  388): handleMessage: E msg.what=131155


I/ActivityThread(14305): Pub com.estrongs.android.provider.fex: com.estrongs.android.pop.FexProvider 
I/ActivityThread(14305): Pub com.estrongs.files: com.estrongs.android.pop.app.FileContentProvider
E/ObjectHelper(14305): Can't find method:setCompatibilityInfo W/System.err(14305): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/.estrongs/hide2.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

I/ActivityManager(  388): Displayed com.estrongs.android.pop/.view.FileExplorerActivity: +4m35s322ms


I/ActivityManager(  388): Process com.estrongs.android.pop (pid 14305) has died.
W/ActivityManager(  388): Force removing ActivityRecord{417b2f88 com.estrongs.android.pop/.view.FileExplorerActivity}: app died, no saved state

I/WindowManager(  388): Input event dispatching timed out sending to application AppWindowToken{41c52bb0 token=Token{416c55d8 ActivityRecord{4159fd50 com.estrongs.android.pop/.view.FileExplorerActivity}}}
E/ActivityManager(  388): ANR in com.estrongs.android.pop (com.estrongs.android.pop/.view.FileExplorerActivity)
E/ActivityManager(  388): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
```

I don't think that the SDcard has any problem, but I'm not an expert on this to say that, so anyone can give me a clue on what could be causing this huge delay to show the contents of the SDcard ?

in Solid Explorer for instance I have 2 windows side by side, the one on the left starts with the root files and folders and that windows is always OK, but the other window on the right showing the contents of /sdcard most of the time shows a black screen with a spinning circle and 10 or 15 minutes later it shows the contents of it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your file /media/your_device_name/.estrongs/hide2.txt is corrupt.  Have you hidden some folders?
Try to correct (or delete? I didn't try) it.
I did the work with Debian (after having connected my tablet via USB cable).
Good luck.

Here is an example; the old file contains:

```
-1 4 root014 5 local011 3 mnt011 6 sdcard012 6 Movies110 8 Pictures011 11 Screenshots110 3 smb010 3 net010 6 search010
```

It shows three hidden folders (Movies, Pictures, Screenshots) erroneously hidden; the working file contains:

```
-1 4 root014 5 local011 3 mnt011 6 sdcard012 6 smb010 3 net010 6 search010
```